# Easy academic CV

Tags: bibliographies, multibib

I am preparing a CV for scientific position - such a CV should include list of publications, conferences, post-conference publications and so on. I thought about using bibliography function for such a task - I could make a CV that would have a few bibliographies, one for list of normal publications, one for conferences and so on. Sounds convenient and could be done with the multibib package, but the problem is - I'm not exactly *citing* anything anywhere. I only need a list. I tried combining multibib with the nocite command, but it doesn't work. Is there a way to generate few bibliographies without any citations in the text?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multibib}

\newcites{conf}{Conferences}
\newcites{publ}{Publications}

\begin{document}
   \nociteconf{Conference2018,Conference2019}
   \nocitepubl{Publication2018,Publication2019}
   \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
   \bibliographyconf{Library}
   \bibliographypubl{Library}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use `biblatex`, there are a couple of options:

### Option 1

If all your conferences are `@inproceedings` and all your publications are `@article`, you can filter by entry type:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{}
\setlength{\biblabelsep}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title=Conferences, type=inproceedings]
\printbibliography[title=Publications, type=article]
\end{document}
```

### Option 2

Or for more fine grained control, you can add entries to categories manually and print separate bibliographies for each category:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{}
\setlength{\biblabelsep}{0pt}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{conf}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{publ}
\addtocategory{conf}{moraux}
\addtocategory{publ}{angenendt,baez/article}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title=Conferences, category=conf]
\printbibliography[title=Publications, category=publ]
\end{document}
```

[image: output for option 2]